# How can we get unused time cost on any subscription in laravel cashier?

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, stripe-payments

This is invoice of stripe subscription that i have creat

```html
$business->businessCashier->findInvoice($id);
```

Above code i am using to retrieve invoice.
But i want the unused time cost to show the same on checkout page.
Can anyone please help me in retrieving unused time when we are going to swap our subscription so that we can create a view so user will know how much amount he has to pay.

I am creating a checkout page where i have to use this unused price.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean, or what you're trying to achieve? I'm not sure I understand your goal here. Are you referring to a proration during an update of some kind?

Comment: I have created a product on stripe with some price.Suppose a user takes subscription for that plan for 1 month and in between of hs subscription he wants to upgrade / downgrade his subscription so how can we determine the proration in laravel cashier.I think you get my points.Basically i am creating a checkout page where i will show all the details how much you have to pay after upgrading/downgrading plan.